# How to use an array of static variables?

Tags: javascript

This is a bit awkward but I need an array of static variables.  Each time a function is called I need access to these variables.  Basically I have an effects functions that is "controlled" by a single variable currently called elapsed_time.

However, I need an elapsed_time for each element that is passed to the function so I can make sure not to run effects on the same element...(for my fade function this causes a flickering effect).

I would like to use the `element.id` to name my variables.

I just read a post saying that associative arrays are not really associative arrays and that you should not use them [here.](http://www.mennovanslooten.nl/blog/post/54)

Below is my current function that I need to update.

```
/**
 *    Effects
 */

var Effects = function( element ) 
{
    this.element = element;
};

Effects.prototype.fade = function( direction, max_time ) 
{
    Effects.elapsed = 0;
/*
    Effects.arrayHold = [];
    Effects.arrayHold.push( this.element.id );
*/
    var persist_element = this.element;
    function next() 
    {
        Effects.elapsed += 10;
        if ( direction === 'up' )
        {
            persist_element.style.opacity = Effects.elapsed / max_time;
        }
        else if ( direction === 'down' )
        {
            persist_element.style.opacity = ( max_time - Effects.elapsed ) / max_time;
        }
        if ( Effects.elapsed <= max_time ) 
        {
            setTimeout( next, 10 );
        }
    }
    next();
    return true;
};
```

Comment: Seriously, look into the [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) functions built into jQuery; there is also a [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/) function; all with duration, easing, and callback functional options. Did I mention the cross-browser capabilities?

Comment: What do you care about some blog post?  Use an associative array when its the best tool and just avoid the pitfalls.

Comment: Don't declare Effects,arrayHold as an array, because you're using it as an object. so better use Effects.objectHold = {persust_element.id : 0}; and take it from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an Object instead of an array